# “Syntax errors” appearing even though none seem to be present

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code that produces a random math quiz. However, when I run it (in an app called SoloLearn) it I get a Syntax error even though there doesn’t appear to be any. I even tested it in JSHint and no Syntax errors seemed to be present. Here is my code:

```
function random(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
function start() {
    var form = document.getElementById("name_form");
    var name = form.elements[0].value;
    var score = 0;
    alert("Let's begin!");
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var num1 = random(10);
        var num2 = random(10);
       var operator = random(2);
       if (operator == 0) {
           var question = prompt(num1 + " + " + num2 + " =");
           var answer = num1 + num2;
       }
       else {
           var question = prompt(num1 + " - " + num2 = " =");
           var answer = num1 - num2;
       }
       if (question == answer) {
           alert("Correct!");
           score++;
       }
       else {
           alert("Incorrect ):");
       }
    }
    document.write(score);
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `num1 + " - " + num2 = " ="`. The `=` should be a plus (`+`)

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: "*I even tested it in JSHint and no Syntax errors seemed to be present*" I copy-pasted your code in jshint.com and got `18 Bad assignment` from it because of `num2 = " ="`. Not really a syntax error but definitely not what you want to do and is definitely an error. A more strict check might flag it as a syntax error, since you probably shouldn't do an assignment as part of a different expression.

Comment: Okay. I was wondering what that meant

Comment: Please accept an answer by clicking on the green checkmark next to any of the answers. If they are correct, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line `var question = prompt(num1 + " - " + num2 = " =");` you have misspelled a '+' which is a '=' in your code.

It should be:

`var question = prompt(num1 + " - " + num2 + " =");`

The same as @Nick Parsons said in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error should be fixed by changing

```
var question = prompt(num1 + " - " + num2 = " =");
```

to

```
var question = prompt(num1 + " - " + num2 + " =");
```

which is the intent I believe